# Second order differential numerically with python

Tags: python, numeric, equation, derivative

I would like to calculate the second order differential equation using `Python` without using build in functions, but the results are correct only for first order equation.

Let me give you an example (No reputation for inset images! - for better equation looks)

`dy/dt = -ky`

And using the basic definition of  derivative

`f'(x)= h ->0  (f(x+h)-f(x))/h`

We can write the basic python code for this equation for k=0.3

```
def first_order(dt):
    t = np.arange(0, 20, dt)
    k = 0.3
    y = np.zeros(len(t))

    y[0] = 5
    for i in range(1, len(t)):
        y[i] = - k* y[i - 1] * dt + y[i-1]

    return t, y
```

And this works fine, but when I try calculate the corresponding equation:

`dp^2/dx^2 = (p- p0)/L`

using:
`f''(x)= h ->0  (f(x+h)-2f(x)+ f(x-h)/h^2`

The initial condition for the second derivative equation is `p(0) = 10^14`, `p0 = 10^13`, `L = 10 ^-6` and `p(infinity) = p0`, the second condition probably makes it wrong.

I trying solve this in straightforward way - similar to the previous

```
def diffusion_lenght(dt):
   p0 = 10 ** 13  # initial state
   t = np.arange(0, 20, dt)
   p = np.zeros(len(t))
   L = 1 * 10 ** -6
   p[0] = 10 ** 14
   p[len(t)-1] = p0

   for i in range(1, len(t)):
      p[i] = (2* p[i-1]- p[i-2]- p0 * dt ** 2 / L) / (1 - dt ** 2 / L)
   print(p)
   return t, p
```

but the results are incorrect. It should gave me the exponential decreesing with `x` but I got the straight line with converge to `dt` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind, I did this few years ago and i have small script for it, so I will give you my code instead of finding errs in yours.

I think its very clear and explicit.

```
import numpy as np

class dif_eq(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def ft4(self,dt,u,x1_before,x2_before,x3_before,x4_before,functionn):
        x1_now = x1_before + dt * x2_before
        x2_now = x2_before + dt * x3_before
        x3_now = x3_before + dt * x4_before
        x4_now = x4_before + dt * functionn(u,x1_before,x2_before,x3_before,x4_before)
        vals = [x1_now,x2_now,x3_now,x4_now]
        return vals

    def ft3(self,dt,u,x1_before,x2_before,x3_before,functionn):
        x1_now = x1_before + dt * x2_before
        x2_now = x2_before + dt * x3_before
        x3_now = x3_before + dt*functionn(u,x1_before,x2_before,x3_before)
        vals = [x1_now,x2_now,x3_now]
        return vals

    def ft2(self,dt,u,x1_before,x2_before,functionn):
        x1_now = x1_before + dt * x2_before
        x2_now = x2_before+  dt * functionn(u,x1_before,x2_before)
        vals = [x1_now,x2_now]
        return vals

    def ft1(self,dt,u,x1_before,functionn):
        x1_now = x1_before + dt*functionn(u,x1_before)
        vals = [x1_now]
        return vals
```

Example of Usage:

```
"""
def order3equation(u,b,c,a): # Your differential equations
    y=u-b*2-c*2.5-a*3.6 #+ noise*np.random.rand()/5
    return y
def order1equation.....
    ....
    return y

d=dif_eq()
val=[0] # init for 1order
val3=[0,0,0] # init for 3order
dt=0.05
result1order=[]
result3order=[]
for i in range(100):
    val=d.ft1(dt,u,val[0],order1equation)
    result1order.append(val[0])

for i in range(1000):
    val3=d.ft3(dt,u,val3[0],val3[1],val3[2],order3equation)
    result3order.append(val3[0])
"""
```

valx/vals are actual values of derivates. First time you pass initial values but then you pass to the function what the function actually returned.

Working Example - Unstable system

```
    u = 1 # input/impulse or whatever name it is
    d=dif_eq()

    val3=[0,0,0]
    dt=0.05

    zz=[]
    def my3(u, b, c, a):
        y = u - b * 1 - c * 1 - a *1
        return y
    for i in range(1000):
        val3=d.ft3(dt,u,val3[0],val3[1],val3[2],my3)
        zz.append(val3[0])
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    plot(zz)
    show()
```

Comment: Hi,
I think that I cleary understood your functions in class but problem appear when you define your own differential equation (In Working Example). So I tried applay your method to solve above equations dy/dt = -ky, with k = 0.3. And the second one dp^2/dx^2 = (p- p0)/L where p(0) = 10^14, p0 = 10^13, L = 10 ^-6 and p(infinity) = p0.
I'm almost certain sure that you can apply your method to solve my first equation but with the second one would be a problem. Becouse in all your examples the initial conditions starts at 0 but in mine equation I have at infinity.

Comment: Both initial conditions are infinite? I am getting exponential btw.  that at some point descreeses and change konvexity. Is this the correct solution https://ibb.co/gWjGaf ?

Comment: In the second equation the initial conditions are: p[0] = 10^14, p[infinity] = p0. 
The right answer are: p(x) = p0 + [p[0] - p0]* exp(-x/L)
Your solution is not correct.
Puting appropriate values we have: p(x) = 10^13 + [10^14 - 10^13]* e^(-x/10^-6) and you can easly plot this right solution and compare with yours.

Comment: I dont understand what does mean p[infinity]=p0. You cant give dif equations conditions for the future

Comment: Well these "initial" conditions have phisical meaning. The first one: p[0] = 10^14 tells you that at x = 0 the concentration of electrons/holes are 10^14 at the beginning of the sample. The second one: p[infinity]=10^13 tells you that at x = far away from the begining (we dont know how far - this equation gives for us the distance) the concentration of electron/holes will fall to 10^13. I solve this equation using these conditions in maple and count the appriopriate limit, and now i wanna do it the same in python numerically. The L here is so called "diffusion lenght" - concentration drop by e